# Embed a CSV file as a table in Outlook mail

Tags: powershell, csv, outlook

I have looked at similar questions but none used PowerShell.

I have a CSV file with 6 columns, I'm able to send it as an attachment via Outlook using the following script:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "xyz@abc.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Ping Test"
$Mail.Body = "Eureka! It works."
$Mail.Attachments.Add("C:\report.csv")
$Mail.Send()
```

I want this CSV file to be displayed as embedded in the mail in form of a table.

Something like this:

[image]

For now I just need one table. I strictly need a way to do this via PowerShell.

My PowerShell version is 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only shown your email code. Since you are successful in sending it as an attachment. I am at a loss as to why the embedded table thing. Oh well, folks have their reasons.

You can't just embed a CSV as a table in email directly as you have it shown/formatted. Convert the CSV to an HTML table and embed the HTML in the email.

There are lots of examples all over the web showing how to do this. Even on this forum.

Example:

> https://thesurlyadmin.com/2013/01/21/how-to-create-html-reports

```
$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
.odd  { background-color:#ffffff; }
.even { background-color:#dddddd; }
</style>
<title>
Title of my Report
</title>
"@
$Pre = "Heading before the report"
$Post = "Footer after the report"

$MyObject | Select 'Folder Name',Owner,'Created On','Last Updated',Size | ConvertTo-HTML -Head $Header -PreContent $Pre -PostContent $Post | Set-AlternatingRows -CSSEvenClass even -CSSOddClass odd
```

> Send HTML Formatted Emails using PowerShell.
>
> Hi,Do you ever want to send an HTML formatted email using
>   powershell.if yes then you can use this script.I am using this scrip
>   very widely in setting up notifications.  The best thing is that we
>   can use this script with any other scripts. To know More info on this
>   script click
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-HTML-Formatted-email-26925a96
>
> How can I embed HTML File in email body
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-HTML-Formatted-email-26925a96

As for ...

> The convert to html report part worked just fine for me. However, I
>   still can't quite embed it in the email body

Are you saying you tried it this way and it did not embed?
Now this is not the pretty bounded table look, because of no HTML styles applied, So, just raw.

```
$DataSet1 = Import-Csv -Path D:\Temp\SomeDataFile1.csv | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
$DataSet2 = Import-Csv -Path D:\Temp\SomeDataFile2.csv | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

$mailBody = 
@"
Hello SomeUser,</br>
Here are the data points requested. Please have a look.</br>
</br>$DataSet1</br>

</br>$DataSet2</br>

Best Regards,</br>
Administrator
"@
```

***Update for OP***

As a quick sanity check, I just did this on one of my lab clients that have Outlook installed and it works for the embed, but and simple table display not using borders.

```
$DataSet1 = Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\DataSet.csv | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
$DataSet2 = Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\DateSet.csv | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

$mailBody = 
@"
Hello SomeUser,</br>
Here are the data points requested. Please have a look.</br>
</br>
$DataSet1
</br>

</br>
$DataSet2
</br>

Best Regards,</br>
Administrator
"@

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "SomeEmailAddress"
$Mail.Subject = "DataSet"
$Mail.HtmlBody = $mailBody
$Mail.Send()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The convert to html report part worked just fine for me. However, I still can't quite embed it in the email body. Due to some restrictions, I prefer to create and send the mail as I have done in the question,i.e, by using the application without supplying an smtp server.

Comment: What restrictions? What Application? (Outlook). Because what is shown in your post is you using the Insert Table option from the Outlook menu. Outlook is just using MS Word under the covers as the render engine for this sort of thing. So, If that is your target approach, then that means Outlook programming using the Outlook DOM using automation.

Comment: Nevermind, I just couldn't get the SMTP server details which was required in the link since it was behind a firewall. Finally, I was able to get through and it worked like a charm. Your update works too. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries. We've all been there at one time or the other. take care.